# How to create X elements in a list based on a variable?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, variables

I am creating sort of a compound interest calculator where and basically want python to create a neat list of every year. I don't have any code for this at the moment, but I will try to explain:

```
years = int(input('how many years?...')) # Lets say we use "3" as input
```

Then, I would like python to create a list containing as many elements that equals to the input from the variable (years). I understand that we have to create numbers in this case that range from 1 to x years.

Presented something like, and even better if the elements where split into individual lines:

```
list_years = [1 years of saving (x), 2 years of saving is (y), 3 year of saving is (z)]
```

I'm not even sure if this is the best way to accomplish what I want, but either way I am very interested in being able to create lists dynamically as a part of my learning process.

Update:

So I have found something that brings me a bit closer to the solution (I believe):

```
totalyears = int(input('how many years?'))

yearlist = [i for i in range(36)]
print(yearlist[1:totalyears +1])

Output: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
yearlist = [i for i in range(36)]
print(yearlist[1:totalyears +1])

#Output: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

## Now i need to be able to change the name of those elements in the file, as well as being able to assign a unique variable to each one of the. Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: #So I have found something that brings me a bit closer to the solution (I believe):

totalyears = int(input('how many years?'))

yearlist = [i for i in range(36)]
print(yearlist[1:totalyears +1])

Output: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
yearlist = [i for i in range(36)]
print(yearlist[1:totalyears +1])

Output: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

#Now i need to be able to change the name of those elements in the file, as well as being able to assign a unique variable to each one of the. Any ideas how to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Something along these lines does the job:

```
def savings_per_year(whichyear):
    return whichyear * 2 # return with whatever function you choose

years = 3

list_years = [savings_per_year(eachyear) for eachyear in range(years)]
```

Then `list_years` will be:

```
[0, 2, 4]
```

Recommend looking up [list comprehension](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/list-comprehensions-in-python).

Comment: Thank you so much, have to experiment a bit with this to see If I can make your code work for me. Will also make sure to look up the list comprehension.

Comment: Really sorry, but didn't get this to work.
Guess I have to study this more in order to understand.

Comment: You can try here: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1SOv141wPF-nTPgoZu7sOR3BN8HgN9a_w

Comment: Thank you so much, I commented further there!